# Apache Spark UDF working fine on spark-shell but failing in jar

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have written one UDF which accepts two arrays of maps. It finds the Map which is not present in the other Map and adds it with new Map return new(Array) + missing Map from old Map.

It works fine in spark-shell but throws NPE when I submit it through a jar.

```
val getr= udf((incr :scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Map[String, String]], lookup : scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Map[String, String]]) => {
    val latest: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String]]= incr.asInstanceOf[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String]]]
    val old= lookup.filter(item=>incr.indexOf(item) == -1)
    latest ++ old

  })
```

Immediate help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use 'new' as a variable. It's a keyword in scala.

Comment: my bad I renamed it to new while posting the question

Comment: Are you executing this code on the same data when you use the jar versus spark-shell? If you're getting a NPE it's probably because you have nulls somewhere in your data which are being passed along until it reaches your UDF where it explodes.

Comment: Dataset is exactly same in both the place .. perhaps it has something to do with wrapped array ..i changed it to seq it worked but i need run couple of times to be sure